# Elevation adjustment DSM using Ground control points

Tags: software-recommendations, accuracy, dem

is there any possibility to improve the vertical accuracy of a given satelite DEM/DSM by using exact measured ground control points? And if so, which software is recommended?

Comment: Wolcome to GIS.SE! Can you please elaborate on the data you are using, maybe the area and what the inaccuracies are you are trying to correct for? If your DEM has a systematic error over a certain area/land cover this would be as easy as using a raster calculator. If you are trying to correct/interpolate over a large area this can get quite a bit more complex.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Kersten. I am not sure yet which data exactly are to be used, but it´s an Geo-Airbus Off-the-shelf product. The strip which should be adjusted is around 200km long and 5-10km wide. Three exactly measured points every 200 meter would be used for the adjustment. The DEM should be calibrated in elevation without distortion. Thanks and best regards, Andreas

Comment: Am I guessing correct that you'll be using the [WorldDEM](http://www.geo-airbusds.com/worlddem/) with 12m pixel spacing? Or will it be something of significantly higher resolution?

Comment: I just checked it out. Most likely it is WorldDEM, maybe Elevation4, but let´s assume WorldDEM.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a DEM/DSM of 200km x 10km and a point measurement grid of 100 x 3 (3 points along the y-axis measured every 200m along the x-axis).

1. Extract the height of the *DEM* below the *measurement* points
2. Calculate the *error* between *DEM* and *measurement* for each loaction.
3. Interpolate the calculated errors to a matrix with the same resolution as your DEM.
4. Correct the original DEM by adding the values of the error matrix to it.

1, 2 and 4 can be done in any GIS Software, e.g. QGIS. For number 3 I would take a look at [`gdal_grid`](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_grid.html).

---

There are some caveats to this:

- the vertical error of your point measurements has to be significantly lower than the 2m/4m vertical accuracy given for the WorldDEM
- quality of the result will depend to a large amount on the interpolation method you choose and the number of *measurements*
- systematic errors might not be corrected or even amplified. If for instance the WorldDEM has poor accuracy over tree cover but high accuracy over open grassland it would be better to interpolate according to the land cover instead of a regular spaced grid.